# SSL implemented on Artemis, but clients with invalid trust stores and user credentials are able to connect to the broker

Tags: ssl, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I'm using JMS on a Spring boot client to connect to an ActiveMQ Artemis broker over SSL. The client is able to connect regardless of the validity of the certificates in the truststore and even if invalid credentials are used. How do I ensure that the broker is filtering clients out based on the configured parameters?

The `acceptors` in the `broker.xml` are defined as show below. The SSL acceptor uses port `61617`.

```xml
<acceptors>
<!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
     <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

     <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
     <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

     <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
     <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

     <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
     <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

     <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
     <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=false</acceptor>
     
     <!-- SSL Acceptor -->
    <acceptor name="netty-ssl-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=E:/apache-artemis-2.18.0/bin/localBroker/etc/sprink.jks;keyStorePassword=changeit;trustStorePath=E:/apache-artemis-2.18.0/bin/localBroker/etc/sprinktrust.ts;trustStorePassword=changeit;needClientAuth=true;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE</acceptor>

 </acceptors>
```

The connection factory, listener, and JmsTemplate are configured on the spring boot client as shown below

```java
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;


import javax.jms.JMSException;


@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MQTTConfig {

    @Value("${activemq.broker-url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${activemq.ssl-url}")
    private String sslUrl;

    @Value("${JMS_BROKER_TRUSTSTORE}")
    private String pathToTrustStore;

    @Value("${JMS_BROKER_KEYSTORE}")
    private String pathToKeystore;

    @Value("${JMS_BROKER_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}")
    private String truststorePassword;

    @Value("${JMS_BROKER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}")
    private String keystorePassword;

    /**
     * Initialise the connection factory that will be used
     */

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisSSLConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61617?&" + "sslEnabled=true&" +
                "trustStorePath=" + pathToTrustStore + "&trustStorePassword=changeit&needClientAuth=true");
        artemisConnectionFactory.setUser("user");
        artemisConnectionFactory.setPassword("password");
        return artemisConnectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Initialise {@link JmsTemplate} as required
     */
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(artemisSSLConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);

        //setting PuSubDomain to true configures JmsTemplate to work with topics instead of queues
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Initialise {@link DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory} as required
     */
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws JMSException {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(artemisSSLConnectionFactory());
        //setting PuSubDomain to true configures the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory to work with topics instead of queues
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

The `artemis-users.properties` file is as shown below

```
admin = ENC(1024...)
system=manager
user=password
guest=password
```

The `artemis-roles.properties` has the below roles defined

```
admins = admin
users=user
```

Admins and users have been given privileges in the `broker.xml` as shown below

```xml
<security-settings>
   <security-setting match="#">
      <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admins, users"/>
      <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admins, users"/>
      <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admins, users"/>
      <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admins, users"/>
      <permission type="createAddress" roles="admins, users"/>
      <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admins, users"/>
      <permission type="consume" roles="admins, users"/>
      <permission type="browse" roles="admins, users"/>
      <permission type="send" roles="admins, users"/>
      <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
      <permission type="manage" roles="admins"/>
   </security-setting>
</security-settings>
```

With the above setup any client with any truststore or username and password is able to connect to the broker on port `61617` and produce and consume messages. What am I missing that is allowing this to happen?

Comment: Can you add your `etc/login.config` as well?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the truststore is "invalid"? How did you test this?

Comment: *What am I missing that is allowing this to happen?*  How is your **server** validating those client connections?  The client's trust store only matters to the client - it's used by the client and only the client to determine if the client trusts your server.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm not using dual SSL auth, just one way auth. The broker.xml file with the "netty-ssl-acceptor" has a keystore and truststore defined and has ssl and clientAuth enabled. The keystore contains a PKCS12 file that is formed by packaging the broker's key pair, truststore contains the root certificate. The truststore on the spring boot client has the root certificate as well, in order to validate the broker. This much I believe, is fine, as this key/trust store setup worked with ActiveMQ 5. Is there an issue with the acceptor or connection factory config?

Comment: When I use anything besides the root certificate in the truststore, the client shouldn't connect to the broker(be it dual auth or one way), but it is connecting regardless, and this lead me to believe the issue might be with the acceptor or connection factory config. Of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: Could you execute another test removing the `acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 ...` from the `broker.xml` file and the `GuestLoginModule` from the `login.config` file?

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino Removing the acceptor had no bearing, this was expected as I was specifying the port the client had to use to connect to the broker. Commenting out the GuestLoginModule worked like a charm, not sure if that's a best practice though. I changed the configuration up a bit. I'll add whatever I've done as an answer. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what got things working.

Firstly, the `login.config` file on Artemis has a `GuestLoginModule` that [this link](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html) says is chained to the `PropertiesLoginModule` and the guest module allows **clients without credentials, or even invalid credentials to connect to the broker**. Now, by default, the `GuestLoginModule` looks like this

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.GuestLoginModule sufficient
    debug=false
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.user="admin"
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.role="admins";
```

Notice that the guests are treated as admins. My `artemis-users.properties` file already has a `guest` user defined (as seen in my original post above), so I created a `guests` group in the `artemis-roles.properties` file and assigned this guest user to this group. I then changed the admin mapping in the `GuestLoginModule` so that the module would reference guests. The `GuestLoginModule` now looks like this:

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.GuestLoginModule sufficient
    debug=false
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.user="guest"
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.role="guests";
```

The security settings in the `broker.xml` file can be modified to accommodate guest functions as per one's relevant use case, mine doesn't have any use case for a `guest` user, so guests have no permissions.

Once this was done, I tried connecting to the broker and got the null cert chain exception. Fixed this by including the keystore in the connection factory config.

Because `needClientAuth` is set to true (dual auth is enabled), Artemis needs the clients to have the relevant keystore built by bundling the key pair derived from the root CA, so my connection factory configuration changed from

```java
@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisSSLConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61617?&" + "sslEnabled=true&" +
            "trustStorePath=" + pathToTrustStore + "&trustStorePassword=changeit&needClientAuth=true");
    artemisConnectionFactory.setUser("user");
    artemisConnectionFactory.setPassword("password");
    return artemisConnectionFactory;
}
```

to

```java
@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisSSLConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61617?&" + "sslEnabled=true&" +
            "trustStorePath=" + pathToTrustStore + "&trustStorePassword=changeit&keyStorePath="+ pathToKeystore +"&keyStorePassword=changeit&needClientAuth=true");
    artemisConnectionFactory.setUser("user");
    artemisConnectionFactory.setPassword("password");
    return artemisConnectionFactory;
}
```

The only difference here is the addition of the keystore path and password. The broker did not connect when it was just the truststore in the config.

If one way auth is needed, just omit the `needClientAuth` field in the acceptor as it is set to `false` by default.

This is what finally worked.

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis is requiring 2-way SSL because the `needClientAuth=true` parameter on the acceptor.

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino You're absolutely right, missed that.

Comment: If guest users have no permissions then you can simply remove the `GuestLoginModule` from your `login.config` and they won't even be allowed to authenticate. It's worth noting that when you create a broker instance it asks if you want to allow guest users. You must have selected to allow guest users otherwise the `GuestLoginModule` would not have been added to `login.config` in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I did allow for guest users during the broker creation. I don't see any use case for guest permissions coming up, so I'll go ahead and remove the `GuestLoginModule`.